# How can I make a responsive scrollbox with seperate text fields?

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to make a scrollbox for my webpage with two separate text fields. I implemented a solution and tested it on my local machine. Later I looked at it from another computer, and the web page was not looking as expected - it placed the right text field under the left one.

What should i do, so that my web page works and looks as expected on every computer? Can you point me to the right direction.

My HTML so far:

```
<style="text/css">
  .scroll {
     padding: 10px;
     height: 280px;
     width:  566px;
     overflow: auto;
</style>

<div class="scroll">
 <p style="margin: 10; float: left;">
   etc <br />
   etc <br />
   etc <br />
 </p>

 <p style="margin-left: 25px; float: left;">
   etc <br />
   etc <br />
   etc <br />
 </p>
```

Comment: @user3569947 You didn't posted any code...so assign `width` to textfields in `%` instead of `px`.

Comment: sorry about this commet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using floats so they don't stack one on top of the other? Of course if your text fields are too wide then you'll need to reduce the size so they have room to appear side by side. As you can see it works in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/6C8cC/).  Added new example with scrolling [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/6C8cC/1/)

HTML

```
  <div id="righttext">
  <input type="text">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:none;"></div>
```

CSS

```
#lefttext, #righttext {
float: left;
}

   #container {
   height: 100px; 
   overflow:scroll;
  }
```

Comment: What you need to do is next the text fields DIVS in a container and give it a height and specify that the overflow is scroll. I've updated the code for you on this page.